# How to perform offline image augmentation using Keras?

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, deep-learning, data-processing

I want to perform **offline image augmentation** for different image classes in my dataset and save the images to one of the folders before I start creating the model.

Using Keras `ImageDataGenerator - flow_from_directory()` which has `save_to_dir` and setting its value to my destination folder

```py
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

datagen_set = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'C:/Users/...',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=32,
        classes = ['class_A'],
        save_to_dir = 'C:/Users/.../AugImages',
        save_prefix = 'class_A',
        save_format = 'jpg')
```

Do I have to create my model and use it's `fit_generator/fit` methods or is there any other way to perform offline image augmentation before creating a model?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save augmented images you needed define a model and use `fit/fit_generator`. Note that `datagen_set` is an iterator so you can use the `next` method to get values from the iterator.

```
for i in range(no_iter):
    image, label = next(datagen_set)
```

The above code will save `batch_size*no_iter` images to the `save_to_dir`.